# while condition or extractall with regex or other to handle new data

Tags: regex, python-3.x, pandas, while-loop

I have a dataset read from a file that I THOUGHT looked like this throughout (500-600 lines total):

```
0,['' '']
1,['Size' 'S']
2,['Energy (kJ)' '1644']
3,['Protein (g)' '20.9']
4,['Carbohydrates (g)' '33.6']
5,['Sugars (g)' '1.8']
6,['Total Fat (g)' '18.7']
7,['Saturated Fat' '4.9']
8,['Trans Fat (g)' '0']
9,['Dietary Fibre (g)' '5.2']
10,['Sodium (mg)' '845']
11,['Serving Size (g)' '180']
```

So I used this code to generate the dataframe I needed:

```
with open("dataset.txt", 'r') as infile:
    l = [x.replace(']', ',').replace("[", '').replace('"', '').replace('\n', '').strip().split(',') for x in infile]
    df = pd.DataFrame(l)
    df['A'] = list(range(len(df.index)))
    del df[2]
    df.rename(columns={1: 'nutrient'}, inplace=True)
    df[['amount_S']] = df['nutrient'].str.extract(pat=r'(?:\'\s\')(S|\d+\.\d+)', expand=True).fillna(0)
    df['nutrient'] = df['nutrient'].str.replace(pat=r'\'\s\'S|\d+',repl ='')
    df['nutrient'] = df['nutrient'].str.replace('\'', repl = '')
    df['nutrient'] = df['nutrient'].str.replace('.', repl='')
```

The dataframe output from the code looks like this (ready to join with another dataset and pivot):

```
             nutrient   A  amount_S
0                       0        0
1                Size   1        S
2        Energy (kJ)    2        0
3        Protein (g)    3     20.9
4  Carbohydrates (g)    4     33.6
5         Sugars (g)    5      1.8
6      Total Fat (g)    6     18.7
7      Saturated Fat    7      4.9
8      Trans Fat (g)    8        0
9  Dietary Fibre (g)    9      5.2
10        Sodium (mg)   10        0
11   Serving Size (g)   11        0
```

Now I have discovered that I also have some entries in my file that look like this:

```
0,['' '' '' '']
1,['Size' 'S' 'Size' 'M']
2,['Energy (kJ)' '351' 'Energy (kJ)' '617']
3,['Protein (g)' '2.3' 'Protein (g)' '4']
4,['Carbohydrates (g)' '15.4' 'Carbohydrates (g)' '26.9']
5,['Sugars (g)' '1.9' 'Sugars (g)' '3.3']
6,['Total Fat (g)' '0.6' 'Total Fat (g)' '1']
7,['Saturated Fat' '0.1' 'Saturated Fat' '0.1']
8,['Trans Fat (g)' '0' 'Trans Fat (g)' '0']
9,['Dietary Fibre (g)' '1.9' 'Dietary Fibre (g)' '3.4']
10,['Sodium (mg)' '2' 'Sodium (mg)' '4']
11,['Serving Size (g)' '75' 'Serving Size (g)' '125']
0,['' '' '' '' '' '' '' '']
1,['Size' 'S' 'Size' 'M' 'Size' 'L' 'Size' 'XL']
2,"['Energy (kJ)' '1431' 'Energy (kJ)' '2030' 'Energy (kJ)' '2863' 'Energy (kJ)' '3383']"
3,"['Protein (g)' '5.7' 'Protein (g)' '8.1' 'Protein (g)' '11.4' 'Protein (g)' '13.5']"
4,"['Carbohydrates (g)' '41.5' 'Carbohydrates (g)' '58.8' 'Carbohydrates (g)' '82.9' 'Carbohydrates (g)' '98']"
5,"['Sugars (g)' '1.2' 'Sugars (g)' '1.7' 'Sugars (g)' '2.4' 'Sugars (g)' '2.9']"
6,"['Total Fat (g)' '17.9' 'Total Fat (g)' '25.4' 'Total Fat (g)' '35.9' 'Total Fat (g)' '42.4']"
7,"['Saturated Fat' '7.9' 'Saturated Fat' '11.2' 'Saturated Fat' '15.8' 'Saturated Fat' '18.7']"
8,"['Trans Fat (g)' '0' 'Trans Fat (g)' '0' 'Trans Fat (g)' '0' 'Trans Fat (g)' '0']"
9,"['Dietary Fibre (g)' '3.7' 'Dietary Fibre (g)' '5.3' 'Dietary Fibre (g)' '7.5' 'Dietary Fibre (g)' '8.8']"
10,"['Sodium (mg)' '305' 'Sodium (mg)' '432.1' 'Sodium (mg)' '609' 'Sodium (mg)' '720']"
11,"['Serving Size (g)' '110' 'Serving Size (g)' '156' 'Serving Size (g)' '220' 'Serving Size (g)' '260']"
```

I would like to move the numerical data to new columns (amount_M, amount_L, amount_XL). The "nutrient" column does not need to be repeated.  What is the best way to go about taking care of these cases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
import ast
# convert output fo 2 column dataframe
df = pd.read_csv('file5.csv', names=['a','b'])
#add comma to ' ', convert each row to lists 
df['b'] = df['b'].str.replace("'\s+'", "','").apply(ast.literal_eval)
#remove rows with 0 in a column
df =  df[df['a'] != 0]
#print (df)

fin = {}
#create dictionary of dataframes - groupby by helper Series - 
# necessary first value 1 for distinguish groups in a column
for i, x in dict(tuple(df.groupby(df['a'].eq(1).cumsum().sub(1)))).items():
#    print (x)

    #create DataFrame with column b, first row is header
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(x.b.values.tolist()[1:], columns=x.b.iloc[0])
    #remove duplicates columns names
    df2 = df2.loc[:, ~df2.columns.duplicated()]
#    print (df2)
    #convert output to dictionary (if necessary)
    fin[i] = df2
```

---

```
print (fin[0])
                Size     S     M
0        Energy (kJ)   351   617
1        Protein (g)   2.3     4
2  Carbohydrates (g)  15.4  26.9
3         Sugars (g)   1.9   3.3
4      Total Fat (g)   0.6     1
5      Saturated Fat   0.1   0.1
6      Trans Fat (g)     0     0
7  Dietary Fibre (g)   1.9   3.4
8        Sodium (mg)     2     4
9   Serving Size (g)    75   125

print (fin[1])
                Size     S      M     L    XL
0        Energy (kJ)  1431   2030  2863  3383
1        Protein (g)   5.7    8.1  11.4  13.5
2  Carbohydrates (g)  41.5   58.8  82.9    98
3         Sugars (g)   1.2    1.7   2.4   2.9
4      Total Fat (g)  17.9   25.4  35.9  42.4
5      Saturated Fat   7.9   11.2  15.8  18.7
6      Trans Fat (g)     0      0     0     0
7  Dietary Fibre (g)   3.7    5.3   7.5   8.8
8        Sodium (mg)   305  432.1   609   720
9   Serving Size (g)   110    156   220   260
```

Comment: Thank you very much this worked but I cant say, even with the comments, that the code is completely clear to me. Is it possible for you to explain explicitly the steps that take place here: 'for i, x in dict(tuple(df.groupby(df['a'].eq(1).cumsum().sub(1)))).items()' ?

Comment: `df['a'].eq(1).cumsum().sub(1)` means compare column `a` with `1` first(`df['a'].eq(1)` is same as `df['a'] == 1`). Then get `True` and `False` values, `Trues` for rows with `1` and `cumsum` create groups. So `True False False  True False` create `1 1 1 2 2` and last `sub 1` subtract `1` for count form 0 - `0 0 0 1 1`. Last `tuple with dict` convert `groupby` object to dictionary of DataFrames and `items()` is for looping.

Answer (score 0):

While you already have your answer, I thought to provide my approach as well.
Here, the different sizes are considered at the creation time of the `DataFrame` with a regular expression and a generator comprehension.

```
(?:
    \G(?!\A)\D+              # match after the last match + non-digit
    (?P<value>\d+(?:\.\d+)?) # capture digits
    |                        # or
    '(?P<key>[A-Z][^']+)'    # match between 'A-Z...'
 )
```

You need the newer `regex` module, see [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/fVtfDy/1).

---

In `Python` this is:

```
import regex as re
import pandas as pd

# construct the regular expression    
rx = re.compile(r'''(?:\G(?!\A)\D+(?P<value>\d+(?:\.\d+)?)|'(?P<key>[A-Z][^']+)')''')

# remove empty lines and lines without any number
valid = re.compile(r'\d+,\D+\d')

# generator comprehension
result = ([m.group('key') if m.group('key') is not None else m.group('value') 
            for m in rx.finditer(line)]
            for line in your_string_here.split('\n')
            if valid.match(line))

df = pd.DataFrame(result, columns = ['nutrition', 'S', 'M', 'L', 'XL'])
print(df)
```

---

Which yields

```
            nutrition     S      M     L    XL
0         Energy (kJ)  1644   None  None  None
1         Protein (g)  20.9   None  None  None
2   Carbohydrates (g)  33.6   None  None  None
3          Sugars (g)   1.8   None  None  None
4       Total Fat (g)  18.7   None  None  None
5       Saturated Fat   4.9   None  None  None
6       Trans Fat (g)     0   None  None  None
7   Dietary Fibre (g)   5.2   None  None  None
8         Sodium (mg)   845   None  None  None
9    Serving Size (g)   180   None  None  None
10        Energy (kJ)   351    617  None  None
11        Protein (g)   2.3      4  None  None
12  Carbohydrates (g)  15.4   26.9  None  None
13         Sugars (g)   1.9    3.3  None  None
14      Total Fat (g)   0.6      1  None  None
15      Saturated Fat   0.1    0.1  None  None
16      Trans Fat (g)     0      0  None  None
17  Dietary Fibre (g)   1.9    3.4  None  None
18        Sodium (mg)     2      4  None  None
19   Serving Size (g)    75    125  None  None
20        Energy (kJ)  1431   2030  2863  3383
```